# Icon hover decrease transition

Tags: html, css, hover, transition

On hover I'm using transition for smooth icon increase. But the problem is that when I drag mouse out of icon it instantly comes back to normal size. I'm not sure how can I do the same with icon decrease. I mean when I drag mouse out of icon it should go to it's normal size with same smooth transition (not instant). I hope you understand me. Here is my code:

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 2.5vh;
 margin-right: 2.5vh;
}

.facebook:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transform: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.instagram:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transform: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.dribble:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transform: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.facebook, .instagram, .dribble {
  transform: scale(0.65);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.65);
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="#"><li><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/facebook-icon.png" class="facebook"></li></a>
   <a target="_blank" href="#"><li><img src="https://awesomeshop.target.com/img/instagram_logo.png" class="instagram"></li>
   <a target="_blank" href="#"><li><img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/assets/favicon-63b2904a073c89b52b19aa08cebc16a154bcf83fee8ecc6439968b1e6db569c7.ico" class="dribble"></li>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put the transition property on your icons, so its not only available on hover.

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 2.5vh;
 margin-right: 2.5vh;
}

.facebook:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  -webkit-transform: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.instagram:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  -webkit-transform: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.dribble:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  -webkit-transform: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.facebook, .instagram, .dribble {
  transform: scale(0.65);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.65);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="#"><li><img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/facebook-icon.png" class="facebook"></li></a>
   <a target="_blank" href="#"><li><img src="https://awesomeshop.target.com/img/instagram_logo.png" class="instagram"></li>
   <a target="_blank" href="#"><li><img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/assets/favicon-63b2904a073c89b52b19aa08cebc16a154bcf83fee8ecc6439968b1e6db569c7.ico" class="dribble"></li>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. You answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the **transition** property for normal image. Kindly follow w3 standard for using elements. `<a>` tag should inside `<li>` tag.

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  margin-left: 2.5vh;
 margin-right: 2.5vh;
}
.facebook:hover,.instagram:hover,.dribble:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transform: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.facebook, .instagram, .dribble {
   transform: scale(0.65);
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.65);
   transition: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
  -webkit-transform: all .2s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<li>
  <a target="_blank" href="#">
    <img  src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/danleech/simple/64/facebook-icon.png" class="facebook">
   </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a target="_blank" href="#">
     <img src="https://awesomeshop.target.com/img/instagram_logo.png" class="instagram">
     </a>
 </li>
<li>
   <a target="_blank" href="#">
      <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/assets/favicon-63b2904a073c89b52b19aa08cebc16a154bcf83fee8ecc6439968b1e6db569c7.ico" class="dribble">
    </a>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the transition property for:

```
.facebook, .instagram, .dribble {
  transform: scale(0.65);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.65);
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
```